# Bixby: Is there a way to mock profile data in the Bixby Studio simulator? Such as Email, Phone, etc (viv.self)

Tags: bixbystudio

I'd like to test out some of the viv.self functionality but I'm only seeing the ability to change Geo/Time/Etc. Is there a way to mock other profile data?

Answer (score 0):

I see MOCK DEVICE DATA in simulator. But nothing happens OnClick(). May be something is coming up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not an answer but an additional question of this..

Is it possible to alter this data during a session?  ie, I want my capsule to be aware of movement taking place so I need the data of location to vary through time during the session.

Also the mock data seems to be in place with the latest release/update.